# iOS Design recommendation for multiple input from User

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

I have an app in the app store which performs verb conjugations in German language for three tenses (Present, Past and Present Perfect). In that app, there is a feature where user can send me a new conjugation for a verb that doesn't exist in the database via in-app email. I present a UITableView with 19 cells divided in four sections. First section consists of a single cell to hold the Verb name, then next three sections consists of six cells each (ich, du, er/sie/es, wir, ihr, Sie/sie) in Present tense, Past tense and Present Perfect.

I just realised that if I were to add Futur or Plu-Perfekt cases, it could be tedious for the user to scroll through 31 cells and enter values in each one of them. Is there a better way of getting multiple inputs from the user without the use of a UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView`s are not very convenient for inputs. Why not use a custom view filled with `UITextField`s and provide a simple navigation like this : https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51681/are-or-previous-next-buttons-better-for-form-navigation-in-ios-7

Comment: I already provide navigation to next input field in the next cell with Next button, but any other way of getting Input from the user?